# Is there a medium power adapter for MacBook chargers?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power

Apple's power adapter allows you to change the "input" from either the default 1-inch "short" attachment:

> [image]

... or a "long" 1.8m [Power Adapter Extension Cable](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK122LL/A/power-adapter-extension-cable?fnode=5129928eb92b1935e3b3a6780e71b1b3286d7a94af63fdc068862c1f44c68609997985976cacf6cf2a5eee21966dd4a3e01125535b5d84538831e1e098a1c0f04dd6cc2e3f24ae6ecffcd948bb63c63ef02e100b4012b1759cd139e07ce5f874):

> [image]

I'm looking for something in between these two:

1. On one end, it should still connect to that round part of the Apple charger:

> [image]

1. On the other end, it should connect to either a 2-prong or 3-prong wall socket:

> [image]

1. It should be at least a little bit longer than the "short" attachment such that it can access hard-to reach outlets without blocking the other outlets. (Right now the short attachment is often hard to use with certain wall outlets where there isn't much access beyond a thin cable.)
2. It should be shorter, and less rigid than the "long" extension cord so that it can easily fit in small backpack. (Right now the large extension cord is very bulky and hard to carry while traveling.)

Are there any 3rd party (or Apple-made) attachments like this, or are these two our only options?

Note that even if the cord length is as short as 6 inches, it would likely fit the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen an Apple power supply connector with a mid-length cord.

As an alternative, my MacBook Air travels with the Apple power supply, the short attachment, and a tightly-rolled 16/2 extension card. If my charge location is adjacent to the wall plug, the short attachment is enough; if it's not close, the extension cord works.

It's cheaper than whatever Apple might offer, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can just buy the cord of your choice.  I use this with mine:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MU1D9VX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MU1D9VX)

It's a standard plug.

Comment: That is…. Not for a MacBook though.

Comment: I'm not sure what "not for a macbook" means.  It's a power cord.  A C7 power cord.  Same connector as on the Apple power brick.  The round lug is irrelevant.

Comment: It's nice to know that will work in a pinch, but the round lug provides an earth. Using the Apple cables stops the laptops from 'buzzing' when you touch them, which is commonly reported when charging.